# Error in ionic live reload

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have downloaded a blank project from ionic and i want the changes to occur live.
I tried 
**ionic run android -l** but it shows an error in by phone **net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT(http://192.168.0.102:8100/)** are the any setting to be done in .js files .??

Comment: That's not very reasonable issue. Sometimes it happens. Just try again.

Comment: i tried the same command for 8-9 time but still same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have installed Cordova Whitelist Plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

To check the plugins, just go to the folder of your application (`cd /yourproject`) and run:

```
cordova plugin list
```

One possible solution if you have already installed whitelist is to make sure that your phone listens to the same network ip as your pc. Reconnect your wifi, and connect pc and device to the same network. Also add in config.xml:

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer.There is also another way by Change the wifi connection to Home Network.It worked out for me

Comment: Thanks a lot, in my ase, I forgot to enable wifi on my device.

Answer (score 0):

add `--livereload-port` or `--livereload-host` , and try `--livereload` again

it fixed my problem.